# hello. i find age. after typing user DOB in textbox1 the age should be shown in textbox2 automatic without any click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code I want to subtract texted year with current year. user will type its year in date of birth textbox, it should show its age in age one textbox without any click event:

[image: this is my code I want to subtract texted year with current year. user will type its year in date of birth textbox, it should show its age in age one textbox without any click event]

I want to subtract texted year with current year. user will type its year in date of birth textbox, it should show its age in age one textbox without any click event

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please do not share code as picture. Please edit your question and use the code formatting tools of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so we drag and drop two text boxes onto the design form.

You get this markup:

```
        BirthDate:<asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthDate" runat="server" 
                    AutoPostBack="True"
                    TextMode="Date">
                  </asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        Age:<asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
```

Bring up the property sheet for the first control - click on the lighting bolt to edit + set the Text changed event.

You see this:

[image]

That jumps you to code behind, and we can write this:

```
Protected Sub txtBirthDate_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtBirthDate.TextChanged

    Dim dtToday As Date = Date.Today
    txtAge.Text = Int(dtToday.Subtract(txtBirthDate.Text).TotalDays / 365)

End Sub
```

so, the end result looks like this:

[image]

and for the c# folks, then this should work:

```
    protected void txtBirthDate_TextChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dtToday = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime dtBirth = DateTime.Parse(txtBirthDate.Text);

        txtAge.Text = ((int)dtToday.Subtract(dtBirth).TotalDays / 365).ToString();
    }
```

Now, of course this does case a post-back. So, over time, you might not want to have a whole page post-back occur. As your skill set grows, then we probably would use JavaScript client side.

But, for now, the above shows how this works. And by setting the the TextMode="Date", then we get a way cool date picker without extra code.

You can of course type in the date by hand, or use that built in date picker.

To advoid a whole page post back? And not have to learn + use JavaScript?

Then you have to drop a script manager on the page, and then drop in a update panel.

Now put the content inside like this:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                BirthDate:<asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthDate" runat="server" 
                            AutoPostBack="True"
                            TextMode="Date">
                          </asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <br />
                Age:<asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

At this point, you now have a ajax like update of the control - we still using code behind, but now we don't' get a whole page post back.

As noted, over time, one could consider JavaScript, but when you starting out, I actually suggest using Update panels, code behind, and thus you can start coding right away with great ease - and you get to use plain jane code behind.

Comment: thank you so much for reply.. but I am not using VB i don't know what is " DIM"

Comment: Ok, I add a c# version of that code in above answer - it really quite much the same idea.

Comment: plz. guide me how can I improve my coding skills kind a beginner right now...